# Change how Awesomium is displayed in Windows Volume mixer

Tags: c#, browser, awesomium

I am making a program and I am using the awesomium webcontrol. But whenever I play a sound from it, eg youtube video, it shows up in the volume mixer as awesomium_rendering_process. I want to change that name and also the icon.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details are in this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/02c8980d-f443-44a3-a710-356b1de60525

Difficulty: Requires working knowledge of COM.

More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I can't get it working for some reason, I can't even find IAudioSessionControl. This could be because I am using WPF, not WinForms, is that possible or not?

Comment: It's a COM interface in Windows directly. There is a CodeProject article that demonstrates how to use it (WASAPI, not IAudioSessionControl specifically) here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control

Comment: Ok thanks , you helped me out there because I couldn't find the API

Comment: I however can't find out how to change the DisplayName?